# Test fixture 'postgres' not found

Tags: python, unit-testing, pytest

I'm setting up unittest to test a postgres connection for an airflow operator. I have a setup function to spin up a postgres container and then a function to test some queries against the container. I'm relatively new to this so no doubt it's my logic not right.

```
class TestOperator:

    def setUp(self):

        #pytest postresql container patches

        postgres_image = fetch(repository="postgres:11.1-alpine")
        postgres = container(
        image="{postgres_image.id}",
        environment={"POSTGRES_USER": "testuser", "POSTGRES_PASSWORD": "testpass"},
        ports={"5432/tcp": None},
        volumes={
            os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), "postgres-init.sql"): {
                "bind": "/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/postgres-init.sql"
            }
        }
        )


    """
    Using Pytest Mocker to create a Postgresql container to connect test.
    """
    def test_postgres_operator(self, mocker, postgres):
        mocker.patch.object(
            PostgresHook,
            "get_connection",
            return_value=Connection(
                conn_id="postgres",
                conn_type="postgres",
                host="localhost",
                login="testuser",
                password="testpass",
                port=postgres.ports["5432/tcp"][0],
            ),
        )

        #target Postgres Container for
        task = PostGresOperator(
            task_id="PostgresOperator",
            postgres_conn_id="postgres_id",
        )

        pg_hook = PostgresHook()

        row_count = pg_hook.get_first("select * from test")[0]
        assert row_count >1
```

I then get the error

```
fixture 'postgres' not found
```

I'm sure my logic is wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

pytest thinks `postgres` is a [fixture](https://docs.pytest.org/en/stable/fixture.html) and fails looking for it.

Instead of having `postgres` passed in as an argument, you could set is as an *instance field*:

```
def setUp(self):
    postgres_image = fetch(repository="postgres:11.1-alpine")
    self.postgres = container(...)

def test_postgres_operator(self, mocker):
    # use self.postgres instead of postgres
```

Or, you could define `postgres` as a [proper pytest fixture](https://docs.pytest.org/en/stable/fixture.html#fixtures-as-function-arguments) to promote better reusability.

Alternatively, you could look into [`pytest-postgresql` plugin](https://pypi.org/project/pytest-postgresql/) which may make it easier to mock out and test postgresql related code.

Comment: How do you define it as fixture? I'm thinking it would be best to define this in a separate class that i can then import to any tests requiring postgres connection. I'm a bit lost with the pytest documentation.

Comment: @Sql_Pete_Belfast normally, it is a function decorated with `@pytest.fixture` and returning, in your case, `container` variable I guess. It takes some time to get used to fixtures, but, once mastered, become incredibly useful tools for writing tests in a modular and reusable manner.

Comment: Yeah I can see the readability is much better.

Comment: `@pytest.fixture(scope="module")
class MockPostgres:
    def __init__(self, Postgresql):
        self.Postgresql = Postgresql

    def db_session(self):
        postgresql = factories.postgresql('postgresql_my_proc',
                                                         load=['postges-init.sql'])
        return postgresql`

Comment: `class MockPostgres:
    def __init__(self, Postgresql):
        self.Postgresql = Postgresql

    @pytest.fixture(scope="module")
    def db_session(self):
        postgresql = factories.postgresql('postgresql_my_proc',
                                                         load=['postges-init.sql'])
        return postgresql
`

Comment: Sorry can't seem to edit my code to appear properly. Does that seem like the right approach? Then what is the best way to call this into my test?

Comment: @Sql_Pete_Belfast I usually defined fixtures as separate functions (not methods in a class). The pytest documentation page on fixtures has some good examples: https://docs.pytest.org/en/stable/fixture.html#fixtures-as-function-arguments. Experiment and, if stuck, you could always ask a separate question here on SO. Thanks.